How to use alternative way of result-document in route Camel?
I am using result-document in an xslt within a for-each-group.
However, when many files are being read and/or written at the same time, sometimes group members are not written to a file.
The log responds: "Error processing exchange. java.io.FileNotFoundException: "The system cannot find the file specified.".
Is there a way to build in some delay, or ...?
<xsl:for-each-group select="node/nodes" group-by="groupID">
    {Delay}
    <xsl:result-document href="concat('FileName_',$pos, '.xml')" method="xml" indent="yes">
    
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group

<?xml version="2.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="xd">

<xd:docscope>
    <xd:option name="delay-function" value="sleep 5000"/>
</xd:docscope>

<xsl:template name="write-with-delay">
    <xsl:param name="filename"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xd:option')['delay-function']"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}">
        <content>Delayed content</content>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node/nodes" group-by="groupID">
        <xsl:variable test="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="write-with-delay">
            <xsl:with-param name="filename" select="concat('FileName_',$pos, '.xml')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


So to be clear you have multiple XSLT running at the same time or is there some other challenge here?

Hi Mark,
There is only one xslt, which should separate output based on group-members.
So, 10 group-members should result in 10 separate XML-files.

Can you reproduce the failure with e.g. Saxon 11 or 12 from the command line? Then add the tag for saxon and details on how to reproduce. If it is Camel specific I suggest you add a tag for that software.

Try putting the attribute saxon:asynchronous="no" on the xsl:result-document call if you have reason to believe that the problem has something to do with xsl:result-document executing asychronously. I don't know what the problem is, but if you think it's a timing problem then this might address it.
